# Access FastImage once it is fetched from url and convert to base64 in react native

Tags: react-native, react-native-fast-image

I have standard fastimage code:

```
<FastImage
    source={{
        uri: imageUrl,
        priority: FastImage.priority.normal,
    }}
/>
```

The issue I am having is that I need to convert this image to base64.  I cannot figure how to access the image file once it is fetched from the server without fetching from the server a second time, which I don't want to do.

Comment: Have you accompolished above one?

Comment: Any update on this one?